# Why do my UITableView cells overlap on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I've created a basic iOS app programmatically (deleted the storyboard). I have also created a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell's, and set the contraints programmatically as well. Before I scroll the table view down, the tableview rows look as they should. But when I scroll, they overlap and things become odd.

Here is what it looks like before I scroll:
[click here for image of app before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojbvh.png)

And here is what the app looks like after scrolling:[click here for image of app after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcA97.png)

I've tried to set a row height, and using the **clipsToBounds** property on both the cell and the tableview. Here is part of my code for the view controller that manages the UITableView:

```
class SocialFeedVC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: teamSelectorContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 3.5).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.register(SocialFeedPostCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellName)
}

extension SocialFeedVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // Define amount of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedPosts.count
    }

    // Define each cell in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellName) as! SocialFeedPostCell
        let feedPost = feedPosts[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(feedPost: feedPost)
        return cell
    }

}
```

My table cell code is also below, but a bit long to due going the programmatic route. Feel free to look at what you wish.

```
import UIKit

class SocialFeedPostCell: UITableViewCell {

    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    let postCreationTimeLabel = UILabel()
    let profilePhoto = UIImageView()

    // Needed with programmatic method
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureProfilePhoto()
        configureNameLabel()
        configrePostCreationTimeLabel()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Update view with controller information accordingly
    func set(feedPost: FeedPost) {
        nameLabel.text = feedPost.nameOfPoster
        postCreationTimeLabel.text = feedPost.creationTimestamp
        profilePhoto.image = UIImage(named: feedPost.profilePhoto)

        // Create post depending on type
        if (feedPost.content.type == PostType.text) {
            let contentLabel: UILabel = {
                let label = UILabel()
                label.numberOfLines = 5
                label.font = Probook.paragraph
                label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2.5
                paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: feedPost.content.text!)
                attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
                label.attributedText = attrString
                return label
            }()
            // Add to subview and provide constraints
            addSubview(contentLabel)
            contentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postCreationTimeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
            contentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -17.5).isActive = true
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        }
        else if (feedPost.content.type == PostType.image) {
            // Create image caption
            let imageCaptionLabel: UILabel = {
                let caption = UILabel()
                caption.numberOfLines = 5
                caption.font = Probook.paragraph
                caption.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2.5
                paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: feedPost.content.imageCaption!)
                attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
                caption.attributedText = attrString
                return caption
            }()
            // Add to subview and provide constraints
            addSubview(imageCaptionLabel)
            imageCaptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageCaptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postCreationTimeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
            imageCaptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            imageCaptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

            // Create image
            let imageView: UIImageView = {
                let image = UIImage(named: "chase")
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                return imageView
            }()
            // Add to subview and provide constraints
            addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageCaptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func configureProfilePhoto() {
        addSubview(profilePhoto)
        profilePhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profilePhoto.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profilePhoto.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        profilePhoto.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePhoto.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 17.5).isActive = true
        profilePhoto.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    func configureNameLabel() {
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        nameLabel.font = Probook.h2
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePhoto.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePhoto.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func configrePostCreationTimeLabel() {
        addSubview(postCreationTimeLabel)
        postCreationTimeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        postCreationTimeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        postCreationTimeLabel.font = Probook.timestamp
        postCreationTimeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        postCreationTimeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        postCreationTimeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include you cell code

Comment: cell code added

Comment: Dont add labels in set call ... because when cell reuse they will not remove them ... e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not "overlapping". The problem is that you're forgetting that cells are *reused*. So a cell that used to say "it's me making a post" but now says "month of Sivan" now says *both*, because you are not removing the old text when you add the new text. You are laying views over the already existing views that you added when the cell was in a different row.

Comment: What is the conventional to remove previous text in a situation like this?

Comment: Oh, you just need to look and see if you've already added the label. If you have, don't add it _again_; reuse the existing label you already added. Or, always look for the label and remove it before adding a new one. Just make sure there's only one! Similarly for the image; don't just add the image to rows that need it, remove it from rows that don't need it.

Comment: A very simple approach is to implement `prepareForReuse` to get rid of _everything_. Now when `set(feedPost:)` comes along, we're starting with an empty cell.

Comment: I used one of your ideas to remove everything before set is called - worked like a charm. I just changed the set function, or else I would use the prepareForReuse. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well done! And welcome to the world of reusable cells! :)