# How to prevent data overlapping in UITableView after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My data displays correctly before any scrolling happens on the UITableView. Once I scroll I see data overlapping and from my understanding it is because cells get reused!  I now understand the concept but not really understanding what my solution needs to be or how/where to implement one (sorry i am very new to swift).  I found this [Why do my UITableView cells overlap on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352687/why-do-my-uitableview-cells-overlap-on-scroll) but again don't really know how to apply it to my code.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        let userNameLabel = UILabel()
        userNameLabel.text = activeUsers[indexPath.row].userFirstName
        userNameLabel.font = userNameLabel.font.withSize(10)
        userNameLabel.sizeToFit()

        let userProfilePic = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        userProfilePic.image = activeUsers[indexPath.row].profilePicImage
        userProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        userProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = false
        userProfilePic.layer.borderColor = WhistleColors.primaryBorderColor.cgColor
        userProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = userProfilePic.frame.size.height / 2
        userProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
        userProfilePic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        let userStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [userProfilePic, userNameLabel])
        userStackView.alignment = .center
        userStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        userStackView.axis = .vertical

        cell.addSubview(userStackView)
        userStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                userStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: cell.frame.size.width / 2),
                userStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: cell.frame.size.height / 2),
            ]
        )
        userProfilePic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                userProfilePic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                userProfilePic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ]
        )

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `cellForRowAt` should not be used to setup cells and their views. Custom cell classes should be used with all of the needed subviews setup. `cellForRowAt` should only pass data to the cell. Cells get reused. You keep adding more and more stack views every time the cell gets reused. There are countless tutorials on using table views and cells correctly. See if you can find some good tutorials to help you out.

Comment: Even though your comment didn't provide an answer it led me to watch a video on basic fundamental understanding of UITableViews and their cells. See my answer! Thanks @HangarRash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concept of tableview is to reuse cells and it's subviews. You are creating subviews on each cell every time when it reloads. Check https://sahilpathania1997.medium.com/how-to-start-with-tableview-in-swift-bf273a8bbabe

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pu7B7uEzP18 and implementing a custom cell class with a prepareForReuse() method.

The first youtube video I ever watched around UITableViews and loading data never went over the concept of "reusable cells". Wondering how many issues like this I will encounter in the future because a concept was not discussed in my learning process! Oh well. Onward. Thanks all

Answer (score -2):

dont use cellForRowAt for creating ui properties.
First of all I suggest you pLease use custom cell for UI creation.
Otherwise its overlap.